# Trying to identify the errors and provide the python code that accomplishes the task

Tags: python

```
age = 3
name = age
if age = "Bob"
print(name is: age)
```

I have to find the errors in this such as "`if age =` should be `if age ==`" and finish the code to accomplish the task.

For the errors I have located the following "`if age =` should be `if age ==` and I also believe that `name = age` doesn't make sense as it should be `name = Bob` as well as `(name is: age)` should be `(name is: "Bob")`.

Please let me know if I correct in my findings of these mistakes and let me know what else I am missing.

Lastly the code I am using to finish accomplish it is as follows

```
name = input("Enter name:")
age = float(input("Enter age:"))

if age == 3:
    print(name is "Bob")
```

This however just gives me a false statement if I enter 3 for the name, please help me

Comment: `is` is a Python keyword operator, and the expression evaluates to `True`/`False`

Comment: you need quotes around 'name is": print ("name is bob")

Comment: Please ***do not*** change your entire question. If you have another one, just click on the `Ask Question` button at the top right of the page. Changing the question makes all of the answers look incorrect, because they don't answer the question as displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing fine, except that I expect the last line should read

```
print ("name is:", name)
```

The original checks to see whether the name is "Bob", printing either **True** or **False**.

Answer (score 0):

print ("name is: ", name) is the correct syntax